# Ошибка при вызове родительского метода

Tags: php

Хочу из дочернего класса *Square* вызвать родительский метод *getSideLength* при помощи `private float $sideLength = parent::getSideLength($coord1, $coord2);;`, но интерпретатор выдает ошибку:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Constant expression contains invalid operations in main.php on line 18
```

При этом, когда создаю переменную $sideLength через конструктор, то ошибки не происходит. Не хочу создавать переменную чере конструктор. Как мне это сделать? Поддерживает ли php ленивые вычисления?
Мой код:

```
<?php

abstract class Figure 
{
    protected function getSideLength(array $coord1, array $coord2) {
        [$x1, $y1] = $coord1;
        [$x2, $y2] = $coord2;
        return sqrt(pow(($x2 - $x1),2) + pow(($y2 - $y1),2));
    }
}

final class Square extends Figure 
{
    private array $coord1;
    private array $coord2;
    private array $coord3;
    private array $coord4;
    private float $sideLength = parent::getSideLength($coord1, $coord2);;

    function __construct(array $coord1, array $coord2, 
                         array $coord3, array $coord4) {
        $this->coord1 = $coord1;
        $this->coord2 = $coord2;
        $this->coord3 = $coord3;
        $this->coord4 = $coord4;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Как мне это сделать? - Создавать переменную через конструктор. Всё.

Comment: тут интересно даже не только, что вы хотите инициализировать поле вызовом функции, которая параметры принимает из того что в конструктор передано, до вызова этого самого конструктор, но еще и то, что вы в вызов этой функции какие-то неизвестные параметры поставляете.